# Renaming files by removing a word from filename

Tags: shell, file-rename, renaming, batch-rename

I want to rename files in a folder that is currently named as `A - f1`, `A - f2`
where `A` is the folder name. I want to do this either in a batch file or shell
script.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
DR=A
cd $DR
for FILE in *
do
  mv "$FILE" "${FILE#$DR - }"
done
```